# JQuery- Adding attributes and params to an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a link

```
<a>href="http://www.ittesters.com></a>
```

I would like to be able to append the following to the end of the href

```
?iframe=true&width=70%&height=85%
```

I also need to insert an attribute

```
rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]
```

I would like this to happen when the user clicks the link not on page load.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Most certainly.  You can add a click event handler to do it for you:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?iframe=true&width=70%&height=85%' );
    $(this).attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto[iframes]');
});
```

You can read more about [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) functions in the jQuery docs.

Comment: Thanks so much! Boy that was such a quick response. Under 1 minute!

Comment: If you have more than one link on your page it would be a good idea to put an id on it like <a id="itter">. Then instead of $('a') you would use $("#itter'). $('a') will register an event handler to ALL the links in your page.

Comment: Instead of creating 3 jQuery objects, you could just create one, change the `attr()` calls, and pass a function to the one for the `href`. `$(this).attr('rel','prettyPhoto[iframes]').attr('href', function(i, href) { return href + "?iframe=true&width=70%&height=85%"; });`

Comment: @Elliot agree 100%.  I left it as `a` for simplicity in the example.  @patrick thanks for the tip - always appreciate learning ways to improve my code.